# Servlet giving error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, servlets, classnotfound

I am using the following code in a servlet of my app

`java.awt.Image awtImg = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(str1);`

When I run the application and call the servlet I get the following error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:834)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:826)
noticeandreports.pdf.appendFiles.PdfFunctionsClass.addSealSpace(PdfFunctionsClass.java:198)
OJ.NoticesandReports.generate_151_OJNotice.execute(generate_151_OJNotice.java:768)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

I have hosted the app on a Linux machine with Java version JDK 1.6.20..

What might be causing the issue...

`noticeandreports.pdf.appendFiles.PdfFunctionsClass` is the class where the code is written and `OJ.NoticesandReports.generate_151_OJNotice` is the servlet that calls the method inside the above class...

Comment: Which JDK do you use? From my experience most linux distributions don't provide the Sun/Oracle JDK by default and other JDKs might be missing that file (it should be located in `rt.jar` which should be on your classpath).

Comment: I am using SUN JDK I am running on Linux Redhat I installed the SUN JDK 1.6.20 in it..and I have the `rt.jar` in my java installed at the location `/opt/jdk1.6.20/jre/lib`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use AWT classes in a server side application, I believe you need to run in ["headless"](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/) mode. Change your servlet container's startup to include:

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

(Or set the system property within your own code if you *really* have to.)

You might also want to consider using an alternative imaging library - either a third-party one or the `javax.imageio` package.

Comment: It was working fine without any error or exception for quite a few days why would it start giving error suddenly??

Comment: S.M.09: The exact same code and no configuration change? No idea. It would have been useful if you'd said that to start with though.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: The exact same code and no configuration change? yes...no change at all...worked fine for quite few days...suddenly today in the morning I stared getting calls from everywhere!! Could it be some kind of corruption?? Cause changing the headless mode did make error disappear...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: There is no internet connection its hosting apps for the local network only...(only for users within a building)..So an auto-update is out of the picture...

Comment: @S.M.09: Okay, that's plain bizarre then. Any chance someone *had* been logged in via an X server which it happened to use, and now they've logged out, giving it nowhere to perform the operations?

Comment: @Jon Skeet:  Not sure of that... perhaps I need to look at the logs and all more carefully...might be something would pop up...for the time being its working fine...is there a way to permanently change the mode of headless, instead of running every time in startup

Answer (score 1):

That is almost certainly not the complete stack trace.  Either that stack trace or an earlier one in the log file will tell you what caused the initialization of `sun.awt.X11.XToolkit` to fail.

However, I'd hazard a guess that the root cause is that the JVM running the web countainer is "headless"; i.e. it doesn't have an accessible display.

The Oracle Java Technical Article entitled ["Using Headless Mode in the Java SE Platform"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html) (by Artem Ananiev and Alla Redko, June 2006) describes the issue and what to do about it.

The solution is probably as simple as adding `-Djava.awt.headless=true` to the JVM options in the web container startup script.  For instance, if you are using Tomcat, add that to the `$JAVA_OPTS` environment variable before calling `catalina.sh`.

Comment: The Sun Technical Article link is missing

Comment: @rajadilipkolli - Can you find the missing article?

Comment: I tried a lot and couldn't find, hence pinged if you can help me

Comment: You obviously didn't look very hard ... 'cos I found it in 2 minutes.  Fixed.