# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit

Tags: java, linux, swing, 32bit-64bit, xubuntu

I'm working on XUbuntu 13.04 and developing swing applications. As I just wanted to try that application I ran into `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit` on startup.

I've found several questions about server/client vms and noticed that I have a server VM and that for Linux 64 there is no client VM anymore. But nevertheless IMHO this problem shouldn't depend on which VM I'm running on.

Has anybody else noticed that problem and has solved it? What am I doing wrong? With 64bit jdk everything works fine, but when I try to use the 32bit jdk the startup fails.

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: Java version is `1.7.0_25` and same with `1.7.0_09`

**EDIT**

When using headless mode, the following exceptions occur:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1272)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1247)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1349)
    at Main.main(Main.java:218)
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:535)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:180)
    at ..MyFrame.<init>(MyFrame.java:23)
```

Comment: Can be the problem described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576986/servlet-giving-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: I considered that option, but with `-Djava.awt.headless=true` there are a couple of `HeadlessException`s. Is this option meant to work with swing applications, too?

Comment: Are exception similar to that described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218870/getting-a-headlessexception-no-x11-display-variable-was-set)?

Comment: Similar, but no message with X11.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362512/unable-to-run-java-gui-programs-with-ubuntu  https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/738b7897-cd38-4f24-9f05-48dd69116837/entry/how_to_resolve_java_exceptions_java_awt_headlessexception7?lang=en

Comment: @bellabax thanks for the many links! I've installed `libxtst6`, `default-jdk`, `default-jre`, `openjdk-6-jdk`, `openjdk-6-jre`, `openjdk-7-jdk`, `openjdk-7-jre`. All of these are mentioned by different Q&A sessions online .. problem still occurs. I've no server/client-application, it's just a client containing the UI. `$ echo $DISPLAY` results in `:0.0`.
I've no idea what I could try else.. maybe I should search if it's even possible to run applications with 32bit java on 64bit machines.

Comment: More alternatives [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13985919/230513).

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Could not instantiate Toolkit: sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Okay, finally I've found the answer. Thanks for the effort! The problem is that I had `libxtst6` installed but only the 64bit-version of it.

`sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386` did the trick for me.

How did I find this answer? I `ldd`ed around a bit, but nothing, as you can see in the following:

```
$ ldd jdk1.7.0_25_x86/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7769000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf76ee000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf76c2000)
    libawt.so => jdk1.7.0_25_x86/jre/lib/i386/xawt/../libawt.so (0xf760f000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf75fd000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf74c9000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0xf74bf000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf74ba000)
    libXtst.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6 (0xf74b2000)
    libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0xf74a2000)
    libjava.so => jdk1.7.0_25_x86/jre/lib/i386/xawt../libjava.so (0xf747e000)
    libjvm.so => not found
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf72d5000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf776a000)
    libjvm.so => not found
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf72b3000)
    libjvm.so => not found
    libverify.so => java/jdk1.7.0_25_x86/jre/lib/i386/xawt/../libverify.so (0xf72a7000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf72a2000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf729b000)
    libjvm.so => not found
```

So that was the point when I ended trusting my IDE and started a sample application on the command line. And the command line again was nice to me:

```
$ jdk1.7.0_25_x86/bin/java Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jdk1.7.0_25_x86/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1957)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1882)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1843)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1061)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1957)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1882)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1087)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:67)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:47)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1646)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1668)
    at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:595)
    at Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

Comment: this fixed issue :

      `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit`

Comment: I was missing another library, but your comment helped to guide me, thanks !
For me it was  libxi6:i386 that was missing.

Comment: Thanks using this command my issue is resolved. sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386

Answer (score 27):

Had the missing awt library problem on Ubuntu 20.04. Fixed it by installing openjdk-11-jre:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jre
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me :)  Obviously as to `openjdk-XX-jre`, one should specify the correct version for `XX`.

Comment: Thank you! This was the solution for me to get Studio3T install to work. 
Just a note: after you install openjdk as above, you need to  **reload your terminal** before re-trying the command that was giving you the error.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for @Bertram's answer. As a complementary, I met similar issue when I'm using Fedora, for anyone who is using CentOS/Fedora and Redhat, please try `yum install libXtst`.

Comment: FYI, I had to install just the `java-17-openjdk` (I had probably only some older java versions after my Fedora upgrades).

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Color com.lowagie.text.Font.setColor(Unknown Source)

On Ubuntu 22.04 using "sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386" command issue  resolved.