# Clipboard copy between server and client in Java

Tags: java, copy, clipboard, paste

I try to create a button that copy in the clipboard a String and then user can paste it.

I can do it when I do my test in local, but when I deploy the application on a server, nothing is saved in clipboard after an user click on button.

Here's my code :

```
public void clipboard() {
        try {
            StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection("test");
            Clipboard clpbrd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            clpbrd.setContents(stringSelection, null);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: java.awt.Toolkit - Does it work in web application? I have used it in desktop application till date.

Comment: This link would help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576986/servlet-giving-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: Thanks, I tried with `-Djava.awt.headless=true` but I have this error `java.awt.HeadlessException`

Comment: ok. Please check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658493/java-awt-headlessexception